# Regularity of the quotient ring $A/f$ implies regularity of $A$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Let $(A,m)$ be a noetherian local ring. And let $f\in m\setminus m^2$, such that $f$ is not a zero divisor. Assume that the quotient ring $A/f$ is regular, then $A$ is regular.

Let $\kappa=A/m$ be the residue field. Since $A/f$ is regular, we know $\dim_\kappa((m/f)/(m/f)^2)=\dim(A/f)=\dim(A)-1$.

But at this point, I don't know how to proceed. I would like  to rewrite $\dim_\kappa((m/f)/(m/f)^2)$ into $\dim_\kappa(m/m^2)-1$ somehow, or to be more precise: find an isomorphism $(m/f)/(m/f)^2\simeq (m/m^2)/V$, with $V$ an one-dimensional subspace.

Comment: My guess is that your subspace $V$ would be generated by the class of $f$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(m/f)^2=(m^2+f)/f$, so $(m/f)/(m/f)^2\simeq m/(m^2+f)\simeq (m/m^2)/\bar f$, where $\bar f$ is the residue class of $f$ in $m/m^2$.